# Empty alternate lists of figures and tables with bicaption

Tags: table-of-contents, captions

I am using the `bicaption` package to have bilingual captions for all figures and tables. However, I don't want to typeset the alternate language in the document's body, but only create lists of figures/table. However, when I use the option `\captionsetup{bi-lang=first}`, the caption is not typeset neither below the figure nor in the alternate list of figures.

A minimum working example follows:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[frenchb,english]{babel}
\usepackage[lang=english,listtype+=FR]{bicaption}

\captionsetup{bi-lang=first}

\usepackage{newfloat}
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[fileext=lof2]{figureFR}
[Figure][Liste des Figures]
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[fileext=lot2]{tableFR}
[Tableau][Liste des Tableaux]

\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\listoffigureFRs

\begin{figure}
\centering
A placeholder for an image or whatever
\bicaption{English text}{Texte en français}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I guess the easiest method to suppress the French caption (but not to suppress the entry in the list of french figures) is replacing `\captionsetup{bi-lang=first}` with `\captionsetup[bi-second]{box=empty,skip=0pt}`. (However, this needs a quite up-to-date version of the (bi)caption package.)

Comment: Hi @Axel, wanna write up an answer and take this one off the unanswered list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the easiest method to suppress the French caption (but not to suppress the entry in the list of french figures) is replacing `\captionsetup{bi-lang=first}` with `\captionsetup[bi-second]{box=empty,skip=0pt}`. (However, this needs a quite up-to-date version of the (bi)caption package.)